# ReactiveValidatedObject missing in ReactiveUI 5.0.2

Tags: .net-4.5, reactiveui

I just start learn ReactiveUI from https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/blob/master/ReactiveUI_4Only.Samples.sln.

I download lastest version via nuget but I cant find class ReactiveValidatedObject in ReactiveUI a check also ReactiveUI.Legacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was removed in anticipation for a new validation framework that didn't actually make it in for 5.0. Copy-paste [this file](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/rxui4/ReactiveUI/Validation.cs) in to get it back.